# C# response from webserver is blank (Unity)

Tags: c#, web-services, unity-game-engine

I want to read values from my web server in my Unity game, but I don't get the response I want. Basically the approach I will show works fine for primitive data types but it doesn't for example array of objects (have multiple int values to return from my database ).

In Unity I do this (Complete code):

```
void Start()
{
    string url = "http://example.com/unitygames/unitywebservice.asmx/GetGameData?='mygamename'";
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest2(www));
}


IEnumerator WaitForRequest2(WWW www)
{
    yield return www;

    if (www.error == null)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.text);
    }
    else
    {
          Debug.Log("Error " + www.text);
    }
```

And in C# Webservice I do this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public List<Int32> GetGameData(string gameName)
{

    List<Int32> myList = new List<Int32>();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SQL_CONNECTION);
    String selectData = "SELECT STATEMENT HERE ..";
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectData, connection)
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read()) {

        myList.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
        myList.Add(reader.GetInt32(1));
        myList.Add(reader.GetInt32(2));
        myList.Add(reader.GetInt32(3));
        myList.Add(reader.GetInt32(4));
        myList.Add(reader.GetInt32(5));
        myList.Add(reader.GetInt32(6));
        myList.Add(reader.GetInt32(7));

    }
    connection.Close();
    return myList;
}
```

The code on web service part works OK, since I've tested it in a browser (it returns what I want), but in Unity I only get this from www.text response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfInt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://example.com/" />
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<WaitForRequest2>c__Iterator1:MoveNext() (at Assets/Networking.cs:69)
```

So why I don't get any proper response from www.text? Am I missing something in the Unity itself?

EDIT: Actual results from the browser

[image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing client side code?

Comment: Sure. I've edit my code.

Comment: What results do you expect or receive when you run it in browser.

Comment: Again I've edited my post. I've attached a screenshot of results in the browser. (database query results).

Answer (score 0):

Try to return from your service [HttpResponseMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx) response instead of the plain List:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public HttpResponseMessage GetGameData(string gameName)
{
    // Get data 
    List<Int32> myList = new List<Int32>();

    // ...

    // Convert myList to JSON or XML string
    // Example of simple JSON conversion for your case / better to use converter
    var json = string.Format("[{0}]", myList.Select(x=>x.ToString()).Aggregate((x,y) => x + ", " + y));

    // Create response
    var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
    // Set content
    httpResponseMessage.Content = json;
    // Set headers content type
    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType =  = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"); // or "application/xml"
    // Set status
    httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

    return httpResponseMessage;
}
```

And then you have to wait until the downloading of the response from server is completed:

```
    public string url = "http://example.com/unitygames/unitywebservice.asmx/GetValues";

    IEnumerator Start() {
        // Start a download of the given URL
        WWW www = new WWW(url);

        // Wait for download to complete
        yield return www;

        // Read the www.text   
    }
```

Comment: Yeah this is pretty straightforward. I already have this in my code.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my response with sample of the server codes which uses  the HttpResponseMessage.